# How to get the full User Manager in Kubuntu 14.04/System Settings

Tags: system-settings

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04, and I want to edit the users/groups lists.  At one time User Management in System Settings did that, but not, apparently, in 14.04.  I just get a stripped-down version that provides no way to add a user to a group, for instance.  How can I get the full User Management facilities to show up in System Settings?  I know this can be done from the command line, but I'm looking for something more friendly since it used to be there.

Answer (score 0):

The program **kuser** does what I want.  (It would be nice if it could be incorporated into System Settings, though.)